# trying to understand how oracle REGEXP_REPLACE work

Tags: oracle11g

Need help being new to "REGEXP_REPLACE".

When I do

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('7ELEVEN USA','[(\D^USA|^CANADA|^Canada)]','') "NAME" from dual
```

I get 7ELEVE and you can see that last character N is missing.

I want to replace first numbers from below & display 7-ELEVEN STORE.

```
20991 7-ELEVEN STORE
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanking in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to replace first numbers from below & display 7-ELEVEN STORE.
>
> 20991 7-ELEVEN STORE

Well, you don't even need regular expressions for that - the good, old `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` does the job just fine (that's RES2). If you want regexp, then this pattern: `^\d+` does it - it says:

- `^` anchor to the beginning of the string
- `\d+` take all digits there are (up to the first non-digit character, which is the space)

An example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '20991 7-ELEVEN STORE' from dual)
  3  select
  4    regexp_replace(col, '^\d+') res1,
  5    substr(col, instr(col, ' ') + 1) res2
  6  from test;

RES1            RES2
--------------- --------------
 7-ELEVEN STORE 7-ELEVEN STORE

SQL>
```

**[EDIT]**

As of the first query you posted (I didn't understand it was the *question*): if you want to select the first "word" from that string, I wouldn't use `REGEXP_REPLACE` but (`REGEXP_`)`SUBSTR`:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '7ELEVEN USA' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+') res1,
  4         substr(col, 1, instr(col, ' ') - 1) res2
  5  from test;

RES1    RES2
------- -------
7ELEVEN 7ELEVEN

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, any help on .......   SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('7ELEVEN USA','[(\D^USA|^CANADA|^Canada)]','') "NAME" from dual

I get 7ELEVE and you can see that last character N is missing.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my message with an example that shows what to do with "7ELEVEN USA" (or "Canada" or anything else). Have a look.